# How to assemble the snake-head axe

Tags: minifigures

I want to make an axe out of the [axe head with snake](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=25276pb01&name=Minifigure,%20Weapon%20Axe%20Head%20with%20Snake%20and%20Trans-Red%20Curved%20Blade%20Pattern&category=%5BMinifigure,%20Weapon%5D#T=P&C=77)

There's a picture of how they did it here: [image: hands of time set]

I don't know how to look up the accessories on the minifig on the right with the axe. Can anyone explain to me the parts used to attache the axe-head there?

Comment: You've linked towards the item on bricklink, you can follow that link further to which sets the item appears in, among them the set of which you posted a picture, selecting that set, you can see the elements in the set, seems straight forward enough to pick the required elements from that list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The axe is made of

- [Minifigure, Weapon Axe Head with Snake and Trans-Red Curved Blade Pattern](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=25276pb01&name=Minifigure,%20Weapon%20Axe%20Head%20with%20Snake%20and%20Trans-Red%20Curved%20Blade%20Pattern&category=%5BMinifigure,%20Weapon%5D#T=P&C=77)
- [Bar 6L with Stop Ring](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=63965&idColor=11#T=C&C=11)
- [Bar 1L with Top Stud and 2 Side Studs (Connector)](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=92690&idColor=77#T=C&C=77)
- [Barb / Claw / Horn - Small](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=53451&idColor=5#T=C&C=5)

as seen on page 5 of the [instructions](https://www.lego.com/cdn/product-assets/product.bi.core.pdf/6205638.pdf) from [set # 70626](https://brickset.com/sets/70626-1/Dawn-of-Iron-Doom)

[image]